# Jmeter script for SSO authentication in Kerberos (Windows)

Tags: jmeter, single-sign-on, performance-testing, kerberos, load-testing

I am trying to implement a Jmeter script (jmeter version 5.1)for SSO functionality with Kerberos.
I have done the set-up in the krb5 and jass conf files and have also updated HTTP Authorization Manager with the Domain,Realm and mechanism as Kerberos.

The script does not output the SAML Response in the URL when running the script. Checking the jmeter logs gives the below error:

```
2020-02-14 12:32:23,453 WARN o.a.j.p.h.c.KerberosManager: Could not log in user gl0
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: null (68)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager.lambda$getSubjectForUser$0(KerberosManager.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager.getSubjectForUser(KerberosManager.java:83) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager.getSubjectForUrl(AuthManager.java:294) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:829) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:572) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1 r1853635]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
    Caused by: sun.security.krb5.KrbException: null (68)
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsRep.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.send(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        at sun.security.krb5.KrbAsReqBuilder.action(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
        ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question doesn't have enough details in order to guess the failure reason, going forward consider adding screenshots of:

1. HTTP Request sampler
2. HTTP Authorization Manager
3. Contents of `krb5.conf` and `jaas.conf` files
4. It would be also beneficial to have more verbose logs, add the next line to log4j2.xml file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
   ```

   and set `sun.security.krb5.debug` system property to `true`

More information:

- [Logging and error messages](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter/)
- [Kerberos Troubleshooting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Hi, Please find attached details:
krb5 conf: [libdefaults]
default_realm = e-glue.com
forwardable=true

[realms]
e-glue.com = {
        kdc = 1.10.64.120
  admin_server=1.10.64.120
}

[domain_realm]
1.10.64.120= e-glue.com
.1.10.64.120= e-glue.com

Jaas conf: JMeter {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    doNotPrompt=false
    useKeyTab=false
    storeKey=false;
};
HTTP Sampler request:
https://ent-028369.e-glue.com:9031/idp/j2Xat/resumeSAML20/idp/SSO.ping
The above url comes as a 302 re-direct from subsequent request.

Comment: It has also been observed that when using HttpClient4 Implementation, the saml response is not seen and the request fails whereas when using Java as Client Implementation it gives a 200 OK response with SAML Response but when checking in Open AM logs it fails with Invalid token.